# IOS lock screen custom text

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In IOS 7 when the user has snoozed an alarm, the lock screen shows a count down in the form of mm:ss. I am wondering if this is a private function that only apple apps can utilize or of it is possible to display any custom text on the lock screen.  Code is preferred, but a link to the api will be accepted (assuming it is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is not possible for you to change something on lock screen.